# perform locfit and plot graph by grouping by multiple variables

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, curve-fitting, tidyr

I have a data:

```
library(locfit)   

a<- c("A",  "A",    "A",    "A",    "A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",    "B",    "B",    "B",    "B",    "B","B",    "C",    "C",    "C",    "C",    "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C")
b<- c("h3c2",   "h3c2", "h3c2", "h3c2", "h3c2","h3c2","h3c2","h3c2","h3c2","h3c2","h3c2","h3c2",    "h1c1", "h1c1", "h1c1", "h1c1", "h1c1","h1c1",  "h5c2", "h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2","h5c2")
c<- c(0,    0.090909091,    0.181818182,    0.272727273,    0.363636364,    0.454545455,    0.545454545,    0.636363636,    0.727272727,    0.818181818,    0.909090909,    1,  0,  0.2,    0.4,    0.6,    0.8,    1,  0,  0.058823529,    0.117647059,    0.176470588,    0.235294118,    0.294117647,    0.352941176,    0.411764706,    0.470588235,    0.529411765,    0.588235294,    0.647058824,    0.705882353,    0.764705882,    0.823529412,    0.882352941,    0.941176471,    1)
d<- c(391.064,  499.769,    575.051,    666.537,    774.666,    859.841,    932.585,    971.25, 996.516,    1002.115,   999.499,    940.548,    242.836,    391.662,    507.624,    507.624,    643.627,    779.394,    195.014,    259.007,    299.504,    310.179,    323.274,    346.793,    381.012,    384.662,    382.25, 434.032,    416.324,    382.021,    402.603,    396.873,    377.478,    367.659,    373.589,    382.506)
dt <- data.table(A = a,
             B= b,   
             data1=c,
             data2=d)
```

I want to group the data by A and B and locfit for each A+B sorted using data2 and data1.

I have been able to sort the data.

```
dt2 <- dt[, .SD[c(1:.N)], by = c('A', 'B')]
```

but I am not able to put locfit along with this.
I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
dt3<- dt[,
     {.SD[c(1:.N)]
       fit<- locfit(data2 ~ data1, data=dt)
       plot(fit, get.data= TRUE)}, by = c('A', 'B')]
```

When I do this, : 
 [I get a graph like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXYxR.jpg)

Where as [I want the graph to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXYY1.jpg)

Any idea how i can get it to work like this?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit**: I found a way to do it using nest function from dplyr. nest the data according to group and map the locfit function to each fo the nested groups.

Comment: Use `setorder(dt, A, B)` or similar, not that `.SD[1:.N]` thing which can be very slow.

Comment: @Frank I tried that but it is not helping.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that as a solution to the problem, just that the line `dt2 <- dt[, .SD[c(1:.N)], by = c('A', 'B')]` is very unidiomatic and bound to be slow. Regarding your main problem, I have no idea, never having heard of locfit.